# power window issues in 06 jetta

Tags: vw, power-windows

I have an 06 vw jetta. The other day I rolled the drivers side window down and it went back up on its own. Now i can't get the window to do anything. I also can't control the passenger side window from the driver side either. On the rare occasion I can get the passenger window, it goes right back up. All other functions on the door panel work.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to some broken contacts in the master door panel switch.

You could try wiggling the switch with some effort, and see if that makes a difference.  At this point fuses may be blown, so check the ones associated with the power windows.

Does the switch operation feel *crunchy*, odd, or make any strange binding noises?

This is only for diagnosis; I don't know of any good way to "fix" such a part.  Your best bet is to replace with a used one from a breaker/junk/scrapyard, or buy the correct used one from a source like eBay.

Fortunately they are not very expensive (used) and it's a fairly simple procedure to swap them out.

Answer (score 0):

On VWs, all power windows can be put up or down from the driver's door with a key (instructions in the owners manual). It sounds like this system may be malfunctioning.

I would suggest using the key in the door to see if this functions properly. The mechanism that actuates putting all the windows up simultaneously may be stuck causing the windows to go back up as soon as they are put down.

You might waste a lot of time trying to find the issue. It may be best to take it to someone who is familiar with VW power windows.